# Changes made to cli's php.ini not taking effect

Tags: linux, php.ini, php, php-cli

I have two `php.ini` files -

- `/etc/php.ini` which loads in case of cli
- `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` which loads in case of browser.

I am able to use PHP's [Mailparse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mailparse.php) extension after adding the line `extension=mailparse.so` in the `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` and restarting lampp.

But I am not able to load the same in case of command line -

getting `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mailparse_msg_create() in ...`

[mailparse_msg_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mailparse-msg-create.php) is a part of the `Mailparse` extension.

I tried by relogging with the user after making the change and even restarting the system.
What needs to be done so that the change takes effect.

**Update**

I checked that `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`
gives

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

**Update 2**
I copied the mailparse.so from `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626` and put it in `/usr/lib/php/modules`. I added `extension=mailparse.so` to `/etc/php.ini` as well. But it still showed this warning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library ...
```

As told by Lekensteyn, I did

```
ldd /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so
```

and got

```
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so'
```

So I gave execute permission. Then

```
ldd /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so
```

showed

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0x00110000) libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0011d000) /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x003aa000)
```

which looks normal. BUt now, running `php` command says

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so: undefined symbol: mbfl_name2no_encoding in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use LAMPP instead of PHP, presumably installed from packages?

Comment: @Lenkensteyn: I am not sure about that :) As far as I remember I had some problems using PHP without LAMPP earlier. I am not even sure if PHP as such needs to be installed so that LAMPP can work or LAMPP does everything. I know these are very stupid questions but I want to clear my doubts. I did not get sites like serverfault two years back when I started all these and these doubts were never cleared. I always feel weak in these things although I am a very confident programmer now :). Thanks

Comment: What distro are you running? LAMPP is an all-in-one package, made to be compatible with many systems (and therefore not optimised / easily extensible compared to distribution packages).

Comment: Fedora 7. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the extension to where your command line version of PHP expects it to be?

Check `extension_dir` in your /etc/php.ini to see where it expects to find extensions and install the extension there or point it at your lampp PHP extensions directory (assuming it is a compatible version of PHP).

Comment: @James Yale:  yes that was the reason. The `extension_dir` in `/etc/php.ini` was different. But, my problem is not fixed yet. How do I install the extension there? Here I have a very basic or probably stupid question. Are there two installations of PHP in my system. I remember I installed mailparse using `pecl install mailparse`. Then how did it affect only the browser PHP and not cli PHP. Also, is "browser PHP" the correct term to use?

Comment: There are almost certainly two installations of PHP on the system. The quickest solution to your problem might be to use the command line version of PHP included with lampp - believe it should be in `/opt/lampp/bin` rather than the other version, then it will use the correct php.ini and associated extensions.

Comment: @James Yale - yes there is a command line executable inside `/opt/lampp/bin`. If I go to that location and run `./php` I am able to run that one. But running `php` only runs the other php. So should I get rid of the other PHP? I am using the Lampp installation for everything. How do I make the lampp's cli as default (run it when I execute `php` from anywhere - without having to do `./path/to/php`).

Comment: You can remove the other installed version of php using your distribution's package manager, eg: `apt-get remove php-cli` (Debian/Ubuntu) or `yum remove php-cli` (RHEL/CentOS). To make the lampp version of php run from anywhere, add it to your path: `PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin`

Comment: I tried `yum remove php-cli` but it failed - gave many `Not Found - Trying other mirror` and then `Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: livna. Please verify its path and try again...`. Also, I already have `PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin` in my `/root/.bash_profile` file. I am logged in as root. Still showing the warning.

Comment: Try `rpm -e php-cli`

Comment: @James Yale- Finally worked. `rpm -e php-cli` gave `error: Failed dependencies: php-cli = 5.2.6-2.fc7 is needed by (installed) php-5.2.6-2.fc7.i386`. So, I did `rpm -e php` first and then `rpm -e php-cli` and it worked. Now running `php` command works perfect. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Both php.ini's contains a different `extension_dir` setting, `/etc/php.ini` seems to set it to `/usr/lib/php/modules` and LAMPP sets it to `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`.

To make Mailparse work for LAMPP, you need to copy mailparse.so to `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626` and add `extension=mailparse.so` to `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` as well. As PHP loads the php.ini file each time run, there is no need to restart your computer.

Comment: Actually Mailparse is working for LAMPP in my case and not with the other installation of PHP (used by cli). So, I copied the `mailparse.so` from `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626` and put it in `/usr/lib/php/modules`. I added `extension=mailparse.so` to `/etc/php.ini` as well. But still showing the warning.

Comment: It looks like mailparse.so has additional dependencies. Can you post the output of `ldd /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so`? If it's a long list, consider putting it in your answer or on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Ok looks like there was a permission issue. It showed `ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so'`. So I gave execute permission. Then `ldd /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so` showed `linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00110000) libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0011d000) /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x003aa000)` which looks normal. BUt now, running `php` command says `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mailparse.so: undefined symbol: mbfl_name2no_encoding in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Added the same to update 2 section in question.

Comment: Have you installed the mbstring extension? (it should.)

Comment: @Lenkensteyn - the problem is solved. check comments to James Yale's answer